# Rotating squares

Tags: plotting, code-review, code-request

I have here an example of how a rotation matrix operates a parametric representation of a square.

```
R15 = {{Cos[π/12], -Sin[π/12]}, {Sin[π/12], Cos[π/12]}};
R30 = {{Cos[π/6], -Sin[π/6]}, {Sin[π/6], Cos[π/6]}};
R45 = {{Cos[π/4], -Sin[π/4]}, {Sin[π/4], Cos[π/4]}};
R60 = {{Cos[π/3], -Sin[π/3]}, {Sin[π/3], Cos[π/3]}};
R75 = {{Cos[(5 π)/12], -Sin[(5 π)/12]}, {Sin[(5 π)/12], Cos[(5 π)/12]}};

r1 = {t, -1};
r2 = {1, t};
r3 = {t, 1};
r4 = {-1, t};
rsq15 = {R15.r1, R15.r2, R15.r3, R15.r4};
rsq30 = {R30.r1, R30.r2, R30.r3, R30.r4};
rsq45 = {R45.r1, R45.r2, R45.r3, R45.r4};
rsq60 = {R60.r1, R60.r2, R60.r3, R60.r4};
rsq75 = {R75.r1, R75.r2, R75.r3, R75.r4};
ParametricPlot[{sq, rsq15, rsq30, rsq45, rsq60, rsq75}, {t, -1, 1}]
```

How would you minimize the amount of code necessary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need a more literal refactoring of your code, rather than bill's [`Line`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Line.html) drawing, consider:

```
R15 = RotationMatrix[π/12];  (* thanks to J. M. ! *)

rr = {{t, -1}, {1, t}, {t, 1}, {-1, t}};

sqrs = NestList[#.R15 &, rr, 5];

ParametricPlot[sqrs, {t, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: `R15 = RotationMatrix[π/12];` is shorter. FWIW, here's how to sidestep the use of `MatrixPower[]` altogether: `rr = {{t, -1}, {1, t}, {t, 1}, {-1, t}}; sqrs = Array[rr.RotationMatrix[(1 - #) π/12] &, 5]; ParametricPlot[sqrs, {t, -1, 1}]`

Comment: Very nice!  Thanks for the lesson. :-)

Answer (score 6):

You could use graphics objects:

```
Graphics[Rotate[Line[{{1,1}, {1,-1}, {-1,-1}, {-1,1}, {1,1}}], #]
    &/@ Range[Pi/16, Pi/2, Pi/16]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I would recommend that such figures be generated from primitives, as in bill's answer. Nevertheless, allow me to present a slight curiosity based on [this math.SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/41954):

```
PolarPlot[Table[Sec[Mod[θ - k π/12, π/2] - π/4], {k, -3, 2}] // Evaluate, {θ, 0, 2 π}]
```

[image: squares]

Answer (score 3):

```
rr = {{t, -1}, {1, t}, {t, 1}, {-1, t}};
rotations = Map[RotationTransform[#][rr] &, Range[0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/5]];
ParametricPlot[rotations, {t, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: You can also use `Graphics@Table[Line@CirclePoints[{1,θ},4], {θ, 0, π, π/8}]`

Answer (score 2):

You've got several choices for the basic square:

```
Line[{{1, 1}, {1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, 1}, {1, 1}}]
```

or, with `FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black]`, either of

```
Polygon@CirclePoints[Sqrt[2], 4]
Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]
```

Then I'd probably use `GeometricTransform`:

```
Graphics[{
  FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black],
  GeometricTransformation[
   Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}],
   RotationMatrix /@ (Pi Range[8]/16)
   ]
  }]
```

But this explicitly constructs all the coordinates:

```
Graphics[{
  FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black],
  Polygon@ Transpose[
    CirclePoints[Sqrt[2], 4] . Transpose[RotationMatrix /@ (Pi Range[8]/16), {2, 3, 1}]] 
   ]
  }]
```