# Reduce Code Length

Tags: list-manipulation, code-review

I have the following that works good, and computes in one shot,but the code is so long. Can someone please help me to reduce the size of this?

```
n01=Flatten[{{{5,0,0},{6,0,0},{6,0,1},{6,0,2},{5,0,2},{4,0,2},{4,0,1},{4,0,0},{5,0,0}}},1];
n02={0,0,0.5}+RotationMatrix[45Degree,{0,0,1}].Transpose[%]//Transpose//N;
n03={0,0,0.5}+RotationMatrix[45Degree,{0,0,1}].Transpose[%]//Transpose//N;
n04={0,0,0.5}+RotationMatrix[45Degree,{0,0,1}].Transpose[%]//Transpose//N;
n05={0,0,0.5}+RotationMatrix[45Degree,{0,0,1}].Transpose[%]//Transpose//N;
n06={0,0,0.5}+RotationMatrix[45Degree,{0,0,1}].Transpose[%]//Transpose//N;
n07={0,0,0.5}+RotationMatrix[45Degree,{0,0,1}].Transpose[%]//Transpose//N;
n08={0,0,0.5}+RotationMatrix[45Degree,{0,0,1}].Transpose[%]//Transpose//N;
n09={0,0,0.5}+RotationMatrix[45Degree,{0,0,1}].Transpose[%]//Transpose//N;
n10={0,0,0.5}+RotationMatrix[45Degree,{0,0,1}].Transpose[%]//Transpose//N;
n11={0,0,0.5}+RotationMatrix[45Degree,{0,0,1}].Transpose[%]//Transpose//N;
n12={0,0,0.5}+RotationMatrix[45Degree,{0,0,1}].Transpose[%]//Transpose//N;
n13={0,0,0.5}+RotationMatrix[45Degree,{0,0,1}].Transpose[%]//Transpose//N;
n14={0,0,0.5}+RotationMatrix[45Degree,{0,0,1}].Transpose[%]//Transpose//N;
n15={0,0,0.5}+RotationMatrix[45Degree,{0,0,1}].Transpose[%]//Transpose//N;
n16={0,0,0.5}+RotationMatrix[45Degree,{0,0,1}].Transpose[%]//Transpose//N;
n17={0,0,0.5}+RotationMatrix[45Degree,{0,0,1}].Transpose[%]//Transpose//N;
n18={0,0,0.5}+RotationMatrix[45Degree,{0,0,1}].Transpose[%]//Transpose//N;
n19={0,0,0.5}+RotationMatrix[45Degree,{0,0,1}].Transpose[%]//Transpose//N;
allPts=List[n01,n02,n03,n04,n05,n06,n07,n08,n09,n10,n11,n12,n13,n14,n15,n16,n17,n18,n19];
```

This generates control points for a B-Spline Surface.

I'm using Mathematica 8.0.4 on Windows 7 Professional.

Comment: Look up `NestList`.

Comment: A... code-golf... that's a code-review... that's on neither site... +1

Comment: @HyperNeutrino I so clicked on that one..

Comment: Closely related, perhaps duplicate: [(146937)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/146937/121)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

since the result of the new computation depends on the previous one we can use `NestList`

```
NestList[N@({0, 0, 0.5} + 
  RotationMatrix[45 Degree, {0, 0, 1}].Transpose[#])\[Transpose] &, n01, 18]
```

Comment: Thanks Ali, and to all who helped.

Answer (score 7):

Another one using NestList:

```
tf = TranslationTransform[{0, 0, 0.5}].RotationTransform[45 Degree, {0, 0, 1}];

allPts = NestList[tf, n01, 18]
```

Answer (score 5):

This is concise and I think it will perform a little better than the methods using `Transpose`.

```
n01 = 
  N[{{5, 0, 0}, {6, 0, 0}, {6, 0, 1}, {6, 0, 2}, {5, 0, 2}, {4, 0, 2}, {4, 0, 1}, {4, 0, 0}, {5, 0, 0}}];

xform =
  AffineTransform[{RotationMatrix[45. °, {0, 0, 1}], {0, 0, 0.5}}];

allPts = NestList[xform, n01, 18];

Short[allPts, 12]
```

> ```
> {{{5., 0., 0.}, {6., 0., 0.}, {6., 0., 1.}, {6., 0., 2.}, {5., 0., 2.}, 
>   {4., 0., 2.}, {4., 0., 1.}, {4., 0., 0.}, {5., 0., 0.}},
>  <<17>>,
>  {{0., 5., 9.}, {0., 6., 9.}, {0., 6., 10.}, {0., 6., 11.}, {0., 5., 11.}, 
>   {0., 4., 11.}, {0., 4., 10.}, {0., 4., 9.}, {0., 5., 9.}}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `RecurrenceTable`:

```
t = Composition[TranslationTransform[{0, 0, .5}], RotationTransform[45 Degree, {0, 0, 1}]];
RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] == t[a[n]], a[1] == n01}, a, {n, 1, 19}] // Short[#, 12] &
```

> {{{5, 0, 0}, {6, 0, 0}, {6, 0, 1}, {6, 0, 2}, {5, 0, 2}, {4, 0, 2}, {4, 0, 1},{4, 0, 0}, {5, 0, 0}},
>     {{3.53553, 3.53553, 0.5}, {4.24264, 4.24264, 0.5}, {4.24264, 4.24264, 1.5}, {4.24264, 4.24264, 2.5}, {3.53553, 3.53553, 2.5},{2.82843, 2.82843, 2.5}, {2.82843, 2.82843, 1.5}, {2.82843, 2.82843, 0.5},{3.53553, 3.53553, 0.5}},
>    <<16>>,
>   {{0., 5., 9.}, {0., 6., 9.}, {0., 6., 10.},{0., 6., 11.}, {0., 5., 11.}, {0., 4., 11.}, {0., 4., 10.}, {0., 4., 9.}, {0., 5., 9.}}}